# zbar with picamera only works once after boot

Tags: python, raspicam, streaming-video

I'm using zbar with python on a raspberry pi to scan barcodes, using the raspicam. (Well I'm attempting to!) The first time I run my python program, it works fine, however, after that, any subsequent runs will fail, and in order for the program to work I must reboot. The error message is

```
error: Invalid argumentfd: 5
zbar.SystemError: ERROR: zbar processor in v412_nq():
   system error: queuing video buffer (VIDIOC_QBUF): No such device (19)
```

and my python code is:

```
import zbar

proc = zbar.Processor() #create processor
proc.parse_config('enable') #enable processor
proc.init('/dev/video0',False) #initialise processor, without outputting a display

for n in [1,2,3]:
    proc.process_one() #wait for a barcode to be read
    for symbol in proc.results:
        print symbol.data
```

I used `uv4l` to get the raspicam to appear at `/dev/video0`

Any help with how I can debug this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have uv4l and also did not install zbar so **this answer is just a guess**

/dev/video0 is (probably) locked the first time you run proc.init('/dev/video0', False) and the lock is not released when the program exits. This is (probably) why the program only works once every reboot.

---

To check if i am right, use `lsof | grep /dev/video0`

If i am wrong, please leave a comment to let me know.

If i am right, you can try `umount /dev/video0` or `kill <pid>` to try and release the lock.
And also leave a comment to let others know